# React Router work on reload, but not when clicking on a link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux, react-router-v4

I have setup the React with `react-router` version 4. The routing works when I enter the URL directly on the browser, however when I click on the link, the URL changes on the browser (e.g http://localhost:8080/categories), but the content don't get updated (But if I do a refresh, it gets updated).

Below is my setup:

The **Routes.js** setup as follows:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

// Components
import Categories from './containers/videos/Categories';
import Videos from './containers/videos/Videos';
import Home from './components/Home';

const routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/videos" component={Videos}/>
    <Route path="/categories" component={Categories}/>
  </Switch>
);

export default routes;
```

The link I use in **Nav.js** are as follows:

```
<Link to="/videos">Videos</Link>
<Link to="/categories">Categories</Link>
```

The **App.js** is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import './app.scss';
import Routes from './../routes';
import Nav from './Nav';

class AppComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <Nav />
        <div className="container">
          <Routes />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppComponent.defaultProps = {
};

export default AppComponent;
```

Comment: Where's your `BrowserRouter`

Comment: Did you get your problem solved? I have exactly the same issue and I'm interested in your final solution.

Comment: @dns_nx The problem I had was putting in the <BrowserRouter> in the wrong place. The correct would be as in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/M9hU4Bg4

Comment: @SuthanBala - your latest commet saved me - after 6Hrs (?!) of spinning in circles. I was not using BrowseRouter at all ... just Router. Jeez ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrapping your component with `withRouter` should do the job for you. `withRouter` is needed for a Component that uses `Link` or any other `Router` props and doesn't receive the `Router props` either directly from `Route` or from the `Parent Component`

Router Props are available to the component when its called like

```
<Route component={App}/>
```

or

```
<Route render={(props) => <App {...props}/>}/>
```

or if you are placing the `Links` as direct children of Router tag like

```
<Router>
     <Link path="/">Home</Link>
</Router>
```

In case when you wish to write the child content within Router as a component, like

```
<Router>
     <App/>
</Router>
```

The Router props won't be available to App and hence, you could pass call it using a Route like

```
<Router>
     <Route component={App}/>
</Router>
```

However withRouter comes in Handy when you want to provide the Router props to a highly nested component. Check this solution

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

class AppComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <Nav />
        <div className="container">
          <Routes />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppComponent.defaultProps = {
};

export default withRouter(AppComponent);
```

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: Nvm, I had the `browserhistory` in the wrong location. Adjusting that fixed it.

Comment: where did you adjust it, i'm have same problem, can you post a full solution?

Comment: If using connect from react-redux, then wrap the withRouter around that connect. ex: `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App))`. Solution for that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082976/3714697

Answer (score 19):

I would go through your components and make sure you have only one `<Router> ... </Router>`.  Also -- *make sure you have a `<Router>...</Router>`* There may be cases when you'd use more than one, but if you accidentally have nested routers (because you were hacking quickly and forgot to remove one when you were moving it around to all kinds of places ;-) - it could cause an issue.

I would try

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
}  from 'react-router-dom'

// Other Imports

...

return (
  <Router>
    <div className="index">
      <Nav /> <!-- In this component you have <Links> -->
      <div className="container">
        <Routes />
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

In your top most component (App.js).

Comment: Double `<Router/>` was the issue in my case.

Comment: switching to Browserrouter instead of just Router worked for me! thanks

Comment: This solution works for me. I used double Router in my app.

Answer (score 5):

There should be only one ROUTER in the whole app, which I think if your head file is App.js, then the ROUTER should wrap the whole App.js component.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same issue, but the cause of mine was much simpler.

In my case I had a space at the end of the URL string:

```
<Link to={ "/myentity/" + id + "/edit " } >Edit</Link>
```

Wouldn't work when I clicked on the link, but the URL would update in the address bar. Tapping on the browser address bar and hitting the `enter` key would then work correctly.

Removing the space fixed it:

```
<Link to={ "/myentity/" + id + "/edit" } >Edit</Link>
```

Pretty obvious I guess, but easy to overlook. A few hairs were pulled before I noticed (and clearly I ended up here), hope it saves someone else a few hairs.

Comment: Thank you! Very easily overlooked

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using the `history` package for navigation and if you are using the `react-router v5`, then you may have to downgrade the `history` package to `4.10.1` until the `history` package developers issue a new release with the fix. As of writing this, the latest release version of `history` package is `v5.0.1`, and if you see a new release than this, you can try with that version first to see if it works, before doing the downgrade to `4.10.1`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this because I have not installed the `react-router` in the application (package.json) dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

You should not wrap the nav-bar where your  are stored in  or

I also had the same issue before. The mistake was the I wrapped my navbar component inside a  you should use  in the main component only (App.js)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Hanly Nadackal is where I found my solution.

As referenced in an issue at the `history` package repository, v5 should not be used for `react-router v5`.
https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/893#issuecomment-905959905

Downgrading `history` at my `package.json` to `^4.10.1` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

React router dom v6 you need to wrap Navbar component inside router

```
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
          <Route exact path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
          <Route exact path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route exact path="blog" element={<Blog />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
```