# React router works only after refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have problem with react router.

This is my  Router:

```
    <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={projetList} />
      <Route path="/dashboard/:id" component={ 
        (props) => <Editor documentID={props.match.params.id} />
      } />
    </div>
    </Router>
```

And Link to:

```
  <Link to="/dashboard">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">
  </Link>
```

Problem description:

When I click my  element - browser try to go to the http://localhost:3000/dashboard
but the site is blank.

When I refresh my site (F5 button) then my component load.

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs when you click on the element?  Like in the chrome tools?

Comment: Check this similar question asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356360/react-router-work-on-reload-but-not-when-clicking-on-a-link. This might help you

Answer (score 1):

Also check out this link: [Routes are not navigating when React v15.5 setup with react-redux v5 is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075400/routes-are-not-navigating-when-react-v15-5-setup-with-react-redux-v5-is/45082976#45082976).  And make sure you put the  in the right place. Check this for example :

```
<browserRouter>
```

https://pastebin.com/M9hU4Bg4