# React Router Link changes path, but doesn't render new component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm trying to use React Router 4.2.2 in order to load a component called PostFocus whenever I click on a 'Card' component, with a Link wrapped around it. When I click on a 'Card' the path changes correctly, but the PostFocus component isn't rendered. Have I done something wrong or missed something out in the Route? I can't figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
class PostsList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var createCards = this.props.posts.map((post, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <Link to={`/${post.id}`}>
                        <Card title={post.title} subtitle={post.subtitle} date={post.date} id={post.id}/>
                    </Link>
                    <Route exact path={`/${post.id}`} render={(post) => (
                        <PostFocus content={post.content}/> 
                    )}/>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {createCards}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

App Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PostsList from '../containers/posts_list.js';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <PostsList />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

index.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './components/App.jsx';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356360/react-router-work-on-reload-but-not-when-clicking-on-a-link/44356956#44356956, it should solve your prblem

Comment: i made the changes and it's still not working :(

Comment: Where did you make the change

Comment: in my App component. Ill post the code in the question

Comment: What's your `router.js` file (or equivalent) look like? I assume you've added the PostFocus route / component to the router definition?

Comment: It still wouldn't work, because PostsList is the one that needs the router props, so you need to either wrap PostsList with withRouter or pass the props from App like `<PostsList {...props}/>`

Comment: thank you Shubham, this did it!

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same problem. I fixed it with a trick.
You might have BrowseRouter in your App.js or index.js, I had it in my index.js like this :

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
                    <App />
                </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I changed it to :-

```
ReactDOM.render((
                    <BrowserRouter>
                      <Route component={App} />
                    </BrowserRouter>
                  ), document.getElementById('root'))
```

and it tricked, actually we are keeping the router look over our complete application by doing this, thus it also checks up with the routing path and automatically renders the view. I hope it helps.

Note:- **Do not forget to import Route in your index.js**

Comment: Wow. Thank you.

Comment: i have the same problem but in my project this don't work

Comment: @Tom Karnaski, could you please provide your code snippet so that I can try to figure out.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/abKzwgpK     or https://github.com/piratezxe/SimpleGalleryAppClient

Comment: @TomKarnaski Hi.. please find the solution below. you need to import BrowserRouter ans implement.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Karnaski
Hi... Sorry for the late reply, I was not getting time to work on it.. Your code is running in my system, I didn't had access to push a branch in your repo.. make your **App.js** like below.. it will work for sure..

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route component={Navbar}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem simply use  tag instead of Link helper. Not sure is it right or not, but it works for me, hope it will helps anybody else.