# React router dom not working with Link, but refreshing the page loads the component

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I've got a create-react-app with a couple of routes. Every now and then as I change branches etc, I notice routing doesn't work. I reckon the only time it has worked its because of caching.

Below are my routes, I've replaced the `blog` route with a simple `p` tag for simplicity as I began to think it was relating to the component I was linking to.

App.tsx

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
...
<Router history={history} data-test="component-app">
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route path="/blog">
         <p>test</p>
      </Route>
   </Switch
</Router>
```

Main.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const Main = () => {

    return (
        <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
    )
}
```

Here's what happens:

- Click on Blog link in Main = route in browser changes to localhost:9600/blog BUT there's no content, just a white page
- Refresh the page whilst on localhost:9600/blog and you get the `<p>test</p>` part

But why isn't it showing test as soon as you click on the link?

Versions I'm using:

- react-router-dom: "^5.2.0"
- react-scripts: "4.0.1"
- react: "^17.0.1"
- history: "^5.0.0"

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router work on reload, but not when clicking on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356360/react-router-work-on-reload-but-not-when-clicking-on-a-link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For React-Router-Dom to work perfectly fine, make sure your entire application is wrapped with **BrowserRouter**  which is best in your indexJS just like that below, a sample of the indexJS file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Adding BrowserRouter will make you render a component in a route directly. <Route path=“/path” render={ComponentName} />

Comment: I had the exact same problem and changing to `BrowserRouter` solved it. You saved me. I'm really curious why `Router ` cause this weird behaviour and `BrowserRouter `.  Any insihgts?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was installing react-router-dom 5, instead of 5.2.0 I previously had. The command is:

> npm install react-router-dom@5

Answer (score 1):

@isidora-lazić, Your solution worked for me.

I had `react-router-dom@5.2.0` installed.

I faced exactly the same issue. So just do this.

```bash
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34478350)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I want to render some JSX inside a ‘Route’ and I don’t want to create a different component I use the ‘render’ prop that receives a function and should return the JSX you want to be rendered.

Try this:

```
<Route path=“/blog” render={() => <p>test</p>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing Router to BrowserRouter in App.js worked!

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
return (
    <Router history={history} data-test="component-app">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Main />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/blog">
          <p>test</p>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
```

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: I had the exact same problem and changing to `BrowserRouter` solved it. You saved me. I'm really curious why `Router ` cause this weird behaviour and `BrowserRouter `.  Any insihgts?

Comment: This also worked for me ✅

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this worked for me by importing BrowserRouter as Router:

**import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';**

and updating **"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"** to **"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"**