# How to fix react router routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on this **React** project for training purposes.
Anyways, I've set up two pages; the **Home** page and the **Checkout** page,
with a **Link** on the **Header** component to get me from *Home* to *Checkout*, this is the *Header* Link code :

```
<Link to="/checkout" className="header__contactsBtns__cart flex ju-co al-it width-auto height-auto">
    <BsCart4 className="header__contactsBtns__cart__icon" />
    <h1>0</h1>
</Link>
```

and this is my `App.js` file :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import "./Assets.css";
import Header from "./Components/Header/Header.js";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer.js";
import Home from "./Pages/Home.js";
import Checkout from "./Pages/Checkout.js";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My problem is that when I click on the **Link** that should take me to **Checkout** page the **url** **changes** to the correct **path** like this : `http://localhost:3000/checkout` but nothing happens, and when I refresh the browser It takes me to the Checkout page.
Ps: I tried to remove the **Switch** and It didn't solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console ?

Comment: Maybe this answers would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356360/react-router-work-on-reload-but-not-when-clicking-on-a-link

Comment: @alegria No it doesn't !

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the code snippets you provided. Can you create a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using something like codesandbox or stackblitz?

Comment: Can you provide the whole code through codesandbox?